# How to make in-app purchase available for TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm building an iOS app that includes In-App Purchases, and I'd like to be able to test the purchases on my app in TestFlight. However, in iTunes Connect, on the In-App Purchases page, I'm unable to submit my product for review and am seeing the message "Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.".

This is where I'm getting hung up. Based on some sites I've found, it seems like I might have to submit my app for review in order to have my product approved. How should I proceed if my app is not complete? I need in-app purchases set up so I can code and test the functionality *before* I submit the app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: @penne12 but will that work if the products haven't been submitted in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I put the app in review state, the warning went away on the "in-app purchases" page, and I was able to test with the products.

I've also realized that it's possible that the products were working before, and there was an error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your In-App Purchases setup properly, the  you can test the purchases locally on the device in debug mode itself with the help of sandbox tester accounts.

For a detailed description, you can use the below link::

https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203809008-iOS-How-to-Test-In-App-Purchases-in-Your-App

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I put the app into review, the warning message on the "in app purchases" page went away and I was able to test the products. I don't think sandbox tester accounts are required anymore -- I was able to test with just my regular Apple ID.